# Like a menu for unbundled legal services

Tags: united-states, software, legal-fees

Can attorneys advertise their flat fees on a third-party site without doing all the things that got Avvo Legal Services in trouble? Didn't Avvo Legal services set the flat fee, handle the payment processing from the client, held the funds until the service was completed, and at the end of the work, Avvo charged the attorney a marketing fee based on the service provided (?) 
But, can a third-party site simply allow attorneys to post their flat fees? Like a menu for unbundled legal services? The attorney controls the flat fee they display and there is no issue of fee splitting.

Comment: Much of the answer will depend on the state (and the State Bar Regulations for that state) where the attorney will perform the legal services. Many state bars have a submission and pre-clearance requirement for lawyer advertising and strict rules regarding fee agreements. If the state where the lawyer practices has none, then the issue is moot. Otherwise, it is a bar issue.